# Redirect urls without extension and slash at the end

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all URL's without extension ( www.mydomain.com/test ) to my homepage EXCEPT the ones which ends with slash ( www.mydomain.com/test/ ).

The following code is working great...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ http://www.mydomain.com [NC,R=301,L]
```

... but it also redirects the URL's which end with slash.

How can I achieve that urls with slash at the end are not redirected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you're asking, you simply need to restrict your match to pages which do not end with a trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$           http://www.mydomain.com  [R]
```

However, this sounds like a Really Bad Idea from a logistic standpoint. But I guess it's not my place to tell you that, so I'll assume you have a good reason to do this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If it does not end in an extension (of 2 to 4 chars)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z]{2,4}$ [NC]
#and it does not end in a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^/]$
#redirect to home page
RewriteRule . http://www.mydomain.com  [L,R=301]
```